# Importing NULL values from CSV in MySQL

Tags: mysql, csv, load

I have a CSV file that contains the following fields and sample data:

```
    year, month, type, port_name, #_people
    2010, Feb, air, test, 100
    2010, Feb, air, test, \N
    2010, Feb, air, test, 100
```

No matter what I seem to try, the server throws an "incorrect integer value" error when I execute the following query:

```
    LOAD DATA INFILE "../uploads/data3.csv"
    INTO TABLE data3
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
    (`year`, `month`, `type`, port_name, `#_people`);
```

I thought this might have something to do with lines terminated by '\n' and '\N' being read as NULL on import. I tried adding a test column:

```
    year, month, type, port_name, #_people, test
    2010, Feb, air, test, 100, 1
    2010, Feb, air, test, \N, 1
    2010, Feb, air, test, 100, 1
```

When I execute the query below, I get no errors and simply need to drop the test column.

```
    LOAD DATA INFILE "../uploads/data3.csv"
    INTO TABLE data3
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
    (`year`, `month`, `type`, port_name, `#_people`);
```

How do I get the server to properly import a CSV that has '\N' values in the last column before the new line?

Comment: \N is not a null value and cannot be imported to a numeric field  so I'm not clear what you want to do here - do you want to transform \N in data to null?

Comment: @P.Salmon yes, I am trying to import NULL values from the CSV to the MySQL tables. Since my dataset has null values, I read in the manual that the server reads '\N' as NULL, so I modified the CSV to replace "" with '\N'.

When I create the test column, the fields with the '\N' are correctly imported as NULL, but I thought there was a more orthodox method.